# Hostinger - Laravel | Image not uploading to the Hostinger public_html folder

Tags: laravel, file-upload

Image won't upload to the public HTML folder of the server

by default, files uploaded through file forms are uploaded in the public folder of the app. Then I hosted the project in Hostinger. File still uploads but in the wrong public folder, not in the public_html folder of hostinger.

here is the filesystems.php where it defines the path of storage

'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'local'),

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Filesystem Disks
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
| may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
| been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
|
| Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
|
*/

'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('/'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('/public_html'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
    ],

    'public_uploads' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path(),
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Symbolic Links
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
| `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
| the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
|
*/

'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

Comment: how do you store the file ? Does the `public_uploads` the driver your are using ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the custom disk define in your `filesystems.php` which is `public_uploads` you are using `public_path` as root. Since `public_path` refer to the `public` folder default by Laravel. So if you want to use the `public_html` where you want to store the image you should use the `base_path()` which is the root application directory and then put the `public_html` folder as its value.

```
'public_uploads` => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => base_path('public_html')
]
```